# How to use a function member pointer in swift?

Tags: swift, function, pointers, member

I am trying to reassign the action a new value "doo" but I'm getting the error "Cannot assign value of type '() -> ()' to type '(myClass) -> () -> ()'"
How can I fix it?

```
class myClass {

    var action = foo    //function pointer

    var actions = [foo, doo] //function pointer array

    var i = 12


    func foo() {
        print("NOP: \(i)")
    }

    func doo() {
        print("doo: \(i)")
    }

    func change()
    {

        action = actions[1] //this compiles

        //Cannot assign value of type '() -> ()' to type '(myClass) -> () -> ()'
        action = doo    //doesn't compile :(


        //... later:
        action(self)() //call the function pointer
    }

}
```

Comment: What  you're seeing is that `foo` is an instance method, without an instance. It's a curried function, first called providing the instance, then called again to provide its args (none). https://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this

```
action = doo
```

with

```
action = type(of:self).doo // or myClass.doo
```

The problem is inside the function `change` you reference `doo` function  with respect to `self` not to the type `myClass` itself

Comment: type(of:self).doo,  myclass.doo  Which one is better? (faster, convenient, etc..)

Comment: you can use **myClass.doo** it's shorter in code and faster as it doesn't consume type of time